# How to convert strings into numbers for pasting in excel?

Tags: python, excel, data-conversion, xlwt

I would like to write a program which paste each element of array (separated by commas) into different column in excel. My code works, but numbers are stored as text not as number. How can I fix it?

```
from xlwt import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
sheet1 = wb.add_sheet('Sheet 1')

my_string = ["aaaaa,123,532","bbbbb,345,678"]
tab=[]
for y in my_string:
    z=y.split(",")
    tab.append(z)

for a in range(0,len(tab)):
    for b in range(0,len(tab[a])):
        print (tab[a][b])
        sheet1.write(a,b,tab[a][b])

wb.save('exxa.xls')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the strings to numbers:

```
my_string = ["aaaaa,123,532","bbbbb,345,678"]
tab=[]
for y in my_string:
    z=y.split(",")
    z[1] = int(z[1])
    z[2] = int(z[2])
    tab.append(z)
```